# Initializing List Attribute of an Object

Tags: python, list, object, constructor, initialization

How do you initialize a list attribute for an instance of an object? I receive an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'Particle' object has no attribute 'image'
```

I tried adding the line `"self.image = []"` immediately after the def line but it made no difference same error.

```
class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self,data,start,finish,width):
        for i in range(start,finish):
            self.image = self.image.append(data[i])
        self.w = width

prtlist = prtlist.append(Particle(samples,int(indices[0]),int(indices[1]),widthcount))
```

I didn't post all the code for brevity. `data` is a list of ints, `start`, `finish` and `width` are ints.

EDIT:

Without self.image = [] declared first the attribute did not exist, with it a variable of type None did not have the function append.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` returns `None`. At the top of the `init` function, you should initialize the list. Afterwards, just append to it **without assigning the return value.**

```
    def __init__(self,data,start,finish,width):
        self.image = []
        for i in range(start,finish):
            self.image.append(data[i])
        self.w = width
```

See the other answer for a more Pythonic implementation. The code shown above simple fixes the problem with minimal modification to the OP's code.

Comment: To be clear, assigning the return value from append (which is, as you say, `None`) should not have caused an `AttributeError: 'Particle' object has no attribute 'image'` error.  That should only have happened if there were no `image` attribute at all, which makes it hard to believe the OP's claim that adding `self.image = []` didn't change things.

Comment: @merlin2011 Ah I see now, updating OP

Comment: @DSM, I guess the OP clarified the point. I answered the question under the inference that adding `self.image = []` had not solved his problem, but not necessarily resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Particle(object):
    def __init__(self,data,start,finish,width):
        self.image = [data[i] for i in range(start,finish)]
        self.w = width
```

Comment: for why the other one wasnt working see the other answer ... basically append returns none

Comment: Yours is definitely more Pythonic! :)